# Orthonormal basis for Sobolev Space $H^1[0,1]$ in one dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $H$ be the space of all absolutely continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $f'\in L_2[0,1]$, equipped with the norm
\begin{align*}
||f||_H=\sqrt{\int_0^1f(x)^2dx + \int_0^1f'(x)^2dx}.
\end{align*}
Then $H$ should be a Hilbert space with inner product
\begin{align*}
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1\big[f(x)g(x)+f'(x)g'(x)\big]dx.
\end{align*}
**My question now is: What is an "easy" orthonormal basis of $H$?**

I know that $O:=\{c_n\ |\ n\in\mathbb N_0\}\cup\{d_n\ |\ n\in\mathbb N_0\}$, where
\begin{align*}
d_0(t):=1,\quad
c_0(t):=\sqrt{3} t,\quad
c_n(t):=\frac{\sqrt{2} \cos (2 \pi  n t)}{\sqrt{4 \pi ^2 n^2+1}},\quad
d_n(t):=\frac{\sqrt{2} \sin (2 \pi  n t)}{\sqrt{4 \pi ^2 n^2+1}},
\end{align*}
is an orthonormal system of $H$, but is it also a basis?

*Background information:* I'm considering the functional $T:H\to\mathbb R$, defined by $Tf:=f(0)$. This functional is linear and bounded in $H$ with $|Tf|\leq||f||_H$. By the Riesz Representation Theorem I would like to find its representative $g\in H$ such that $Tf=\langle f,g\rangle$ for all $f\in H$.

I know that if $(e_n)$ is an orthonomal basis of $H$, then $g=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}Te_n\cdot e_n$. I tried $O$ and came up with some weird function $g$, for which I tested numerically if $g$ is the desired representative. However, these tests seem like $g$ is not the representative, and that's why I doubt that $O$ is complete.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: The part '*in one dimension*' in the title is misleading.

Comment: Also, I am not sure that $T$ is well defined as it stands..

Comment: What exactly is misleading about "in one dimension"? The functions I'm considering are defined on a real interval and attain real values, so everything is one-dimensional. Moreover, why is $T$ not well defined? Since $H$ contains only continuous functions, I can evaluate every function at a single point...

Comment: Your definition of the norm here has a typo. The root should encompass the whole sum.

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake by considering $c_0=\sqrt{3}t$, which neither is normalized nor orthogonal to the other functions. However, my question has already been answered here:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261941/orthonormal-basis-in-w1-20-1